# chart category control on merge with openTBS

Tags: charts, libreoffice, opentbs

I want to create a LibreOffice Impress template with a chart inside. The category's list depend on the domain the document is generated for. It may be "A, B, C" or "D, E, F, G".

If my template chart has categories "A, B, C", it works for domain 1, but not for domain 2 where my document will have a chart with categories "A, B, C, D, E, F, G", all 3 firts categories beeing null.
If my template chart has category "foo", both domain will have "foo" as first category.

How do I make sure my chart will have the only categories I give them when it will be time to merge them?

Comment: For now this is a bug with charts with LibreOffice : empty categories remain displayed in the chard even if there is no more data associated with the category. This does not happen with Ms Office because unused categories are never displayed. This will be fixed in next version.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to solve since OpenTBS version 1.9.11.

The new command OPENTBS_CHART_DELETE_CATEGORY enables you to delete any category in a chart. You can delete all categories one by one, and then add new categories by defining new data series with OPENTBS_CHART.